# Get random number between two numbers in Scala

Tags: scala, random

How do I get a random number between two numbers say 20 to 30?

I tried:

```
val r = new scala.util.Random
r.nextInt(30)
```

This allows only upper bound value, but values always starts with 0. Is there a way to set lower bound value (to 20 in the example)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 58):

You can use below. Both start and end will be inclusive.

```
val start = 20
val end   = 30
val rnd = new scala.util.Random
start + rnd.nextInt( (end - start) + 1 )
```

In your case

```
val r = new scala.util.Random
val r1 = 20 + r.nextInt(( 30 - 20) + 1)
```

Answer (score 56):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, [`scala.util.Random`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Random$.html) provides:

[`def between(minInclusive: Int, maxExclusive: Int): Int`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Random.html#between(minInclusive:Int,maxExclusive:Int):Int)

which used as follow, generates an `Int` between 20 (included) and 30 (excluded):

```
import scala.util.Random
Random.between(20, 30) // in [20, 30[
```

Answer (score 28):

Sure. Just do

```
// random number between 20 and 30 inclusive
val r = new scala.util.Random
20 + r.nextInt(11)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) as an option. It's preferable in multithreaded environments.

```
val random: ThreadLocalRandom = ThreadLocalRandom.current()
val r = random.nextLong(20, 30 + 1) // returns value between 20 and 30 inclusively
```

Answer (score 8):

Also scaling `math.random` value which ranges between `0` and `1` to the interval of interest, and converting the `Double` in this case to `Int`, e.g.

```
(math.random * (30-20) + 20).toInt
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `Random.between(a, b)`
Note that `a` in inclusive, and `b` is exclusive.
Refer to documentation [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Random.html#between(minInclusive:Int,maxExclusive:Int):Int).

```scala
val r = new scala.util.Random

//to print 10 random numbers between 20 and 30 inclusive
(1 to 10).foreach(x => 
  println(r.between(20, 30+1))
)
```

Output

```
28
26
29
30
22
29
28
22
20
24

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This just duplicates [one of the top answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53384424/9297144)